# Match first part of filepath strings

Tags: c#, optimization, memory-management

I have a simple class like the following:

```
class Record
{
    public Record(string fp1, string fp2, string fp3)
    {
        Filepath1 = fp1;
        Filepath2 = fp2;
        Filepath3 = fp3;
    }

    public string Filepath1 { get; private set; }
    public string Filepath2 { get; private set; }
    public string Filepath3 { get; private set; }
}
```

Each of these filepaths will be very similar (and very long), and will only differ toward the last few characters of the filepath.

Now, I want to have several thousand of these Records in memory, and I would like these records to use up a smaller amount of RAM. So I am trying to think of ways to optimize memory usage, and here is one solution that I came up with:

```
class Record
{
    private string _baseFilepath;
    private string _fp1;
    private string _fp2;
    private string _fp3;
    public Record(string fp1, string fp2, string fp3)
    {
        _baseFilepath = /*get common first part of filepaths*/;
        _fp1 = /*last part of fp1*/;
        _fp2 = /*last part of fp2*/;
        _fp3 = /*last part of fp3*/;
    }

    public string Filepath1
    {
        get { return _baseFilepath + _fp1; }
    }

    public string Filepath2
    {
        get { return _baseFilepath + _fp2; }
    }

    public string Filepath3
    {
        get { return _baseFilepath + _fp3; }
    }
}
```

You can see that I could save a lot of RAM, especially with really long filepaths where only the last few characters are different. The question is, is there an easy way to get the common first part of the filepath?

EDIT:
There could be up to 700,000 Records in memory, and the actual production class has several more filepaths. I'm trying to make the app as lightweight as possible, while trying to keep the optimizations extremely simple for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Thousands of records will occupy a megabyte or so. Are you operating on severely constrained hardware?

Comment: It depends, actually. This is for a server app, and each user that is connected to the server will probably cause 4000 records to be in memory.

Comment: Oh, and this isn't my production class, just an example. There will be many more filepaths in real life.

Comment: Is this a real file path or did you just name it this way? If so do they differ only in the actual file name and you want to split out the path? If that's the task `Path.GetDirectoryName()` etc. probably should be used.

Comment: @Marcelo Not sure. I'm estimating 700 users (hopefully that's a gross overestimate)

Comment: @BrokenGlass Path.GetDirectoryName should be a decent solution, but parts of the actual file names could also be included. Also, the files are not guaranteed to be in the same directory.

Comment: @Phil: There are a few more variables there than first meet the eye. The very first question to ask yourself is, how much total memory will the naïve solution use in real life? If it's less than a few tens of megabytes, then I wouldn't complicate my code, my debugging experience and my life with optimising the above class. (Obviously, though, the balance will tip the other way at some point.)

Comment: @Marcelo I completely agree for most scenarios. However I think this optimization isn't very complicated at all, and I think this could give me a bit more headroom, not to mention make my app quite a bit more lightweight. Only experimentation will tell.

Comment: @Phil: I look at all complexity with a jaundiced eye. Performance should always be secondary to simplicity. It's only a small thing, but there are many such opportunities to introduce small improvements like this, and the end result can be unwieldy; also, there is a non-trivial impact during debugging, because you will have to mentally concatenate when inspecting these variables, and another programmer might get confused and burn hours on a wild goose chase if they don't notice how the class works. Ultimately, though, I agree with you; it really boils down to where your threshold of pain lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do it:

```
public static string GetCommonStart(string fp1, string fp2, string fp3)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int minLength = Math.Min(Math.Min(fp1.Length, fp2.Length), fp3.Length);
    while (idx < minLength && fp1[idx] == fp2[idx] && fp2[idx] == fp3[idx])
       idx++;
    return fp1.Substring(0, idx);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I would add a check to make sure that you don't go over the length of the shortest string. ex `c:\1.jpg` and `c:\1.jpg.jpg` would error out. Edit, just like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, if this action is not performance-critical to you:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string GetCommonPrefix(string a, string b)
    {
        int commonPrefixLength = 0;
        int minimumLength = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < minimumLength; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                commonPrefixLength++;
            }
        }

        return a.Substring(0, commonPrefixLength);
    }

    public static string GetCommonPrefix(params string[] strings)
    {
        return strings.Aggregate(GetCommonPrefix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this a supplementary answer, providing an alternate suggestion rather than a straight answer to your problem (which have already been supplied).

If possible, I'd break these filepaths into `base` and `suffix` at the first possible opportunity & then pass in that manner through your entire system.

This is applicable if

- you are generating these filepaths yourself, somewhere in your system
- you are reading files from a known & finite set of locations

You would simply have a set of `base` filepaths, and each `Filepath` references once of those `base` values and also contains its own `suffix` value.

Depending on the number of `base` filepaths & how they were determined, this would be significantly more memory efficient.  Your current solution gives best case one-third memory use (each three filepaths are best optimized into one filepath).  It also makes sense to store this object (`filepath`) in a consistent manner across your entire app.